# How to print to stdout while save the stdout to string at the same time in golang?

Tags: go, operating-system

What I want to do is like:

```
cmd := exec.Command(someCommand)
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Run()
save(os.Stdout)
```

Because this command takes a long time executing, I want to print results on the screen immediately. So I do not want to use `result := cmd.Output() fmt.Print(result)` to save the output and then print

Comment: implement a `io.Writer` which write to file and stdout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa a [MultiWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter):

```
cmd := exec.Command(someCommand)
var buf bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, &buf)
cmd.Run()
save(buf.Bytes())  // Bytes() returns a []byte containing the stdout from the commmand.
```

Comment: Amazing and elegant!